# Motorola Atrix 2 native camera app failing

Tags: camera, motorola-atrix-4g

I use the native camera app and many of my recent pictures either have a large grey area with no information:

[image: large grey area]

or noise in the picture made of bits of another picture:

[image: noise]

Is this a known problem?  It was happening again last night with great frequency, so I  restarted the phone and the next picture was fine.

---

Edit:  I have since removed all 752 pictures. I shot a few more, and still had at least one shot with each of the problems presented here.  I believe I will try a 3rd-party camera.

Comment: This might as well be a *storage* problem. The first pic looks like a partially saved .jpg (the grey area representing the cut off part). The second picture has the correct size but contains *foreign* image data... Have you checked where pictures go to? Internal or SD card? (the Atrix has 16gb internal and up to 32gb via micro SD). Do you have similar problems with other apps that use the internal storage? Here's the [catlog log viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat), can you check your device logs next time you have this problem?

Comment: @ce4 A problem of storage seems likely.  I will offload most of the pictures and see whether that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my SD card was failing.  I have since replaced it and all pictures are fine thus far.